# how to get date column of csv and use it as x-axis in a chart?

Tags: c#, datetime, csv, graph

In my Windows forms application I'm trying to get a CSV file which as 2 columns.First for date and second for values.The problem is after I take my csv file I get an error.It says string was not recognized as a valid datetime. 
Here is my code:

```
            string dosyaAdi;                                
            private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
              {
              try     
             {

             DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dosyaAdi = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }


            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(dosyaAdi));

             List<string> zaman = new List<string>();

             List<string> deger = new List<string>();

             while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var satir = reader.ReadLine();
                var degerler = satir.Split(',');
                if (degerler.Count() > 1)
                {
                    zaman.Add(degerler[0]);
                    deger.Add(degerler[1]);
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Zaman ve değer listelere atıldı");
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            DateTime newdatetime = new DateTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < zaman.Count; i++)
            {
                newdatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(zaman[i], "M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(newdatetime.ToString("M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < deger.Count; j++)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(deger[j]);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

any help would be much appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Can you give us a line from the CSV?

Comment: @bdimag sure for example first line is like this 09/18/2014 23:15:08.170 3.2573974589612531

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a valid format string:

```
        string toParse = "09/18/2014 23:15:08.170";
        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: sorry but I'm still having the same problem :/

Comment: What is the updated line of code using ParseExact, and what is the input that it fails on?

Comment: the thing I see when I put breakpoint,nothing about date values are filling the list.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, what is the value of `zaman[i]` at the time that the error occurs?

Comment: it says count=2   [0] "552\tSSK" string and also   [1] "1154\tFaiz swap IRS eval" string

Comment: There's a problem with either your parsing, logic or input data. "552\tSSK" is not a valid date.

Comment: I found out that I have a problem in my csv file so I generate a new one.The first line is like this : 09/18/2014 00:00:08.233,"2.953523398399216" @user1112560

Comment: @user1112660 unfortunately yes,it still has the same error

Comment: Is the line it fails on a valid date? If so, what is `zaman[i]`?

Comment: zaman is the list that I save the time.It's the first column of my csv file.Left side of comma.Right side is the values which I save in a list called deger.

Comment: I realise, what is the data in `zaman[i]` at the point where the parsing of a date fails.

Comment: it takes the values of time column as i wanted.I changed i from 0 to 1 because first row is like header.But I still get the same problem

Comment: What is the data that causes the problem? Is it a date?

Comment: and also after the newdatetime's parseExact row it directly falls into catch block from try block.It doesn't go on

Comment: can it be because first line is header?

Comment: I don't have your data to hand. I can't help you unless you provide the row that is causing the error. If you have invalid data, then due to the try... catch block, the method will fail to write the chart.

Comment: I can send the csv if you want to? @user1112560

Answer (score 0):

with `DateTime.ParseExact` the string to parse must match exactly the format provided... in your case, you should have.

```
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

THere's also Parse and TryParse, which would be a little more relaxed

Comment: sorry but the problem is still the same